# Bounding difference of two mutual information with different distributions on random variables

Tags: pr.probability, inequalities, entropy

Let $A$, $B$ and $C$ be three random variables and $p_{A,B,C}=p_Ap_Bp_{C|A,B}$ and $q_{A,B,C}=p_Aq_{B|A}p_{C|A,B}$ be two distributions on them. Then, we can conclude that?
\begin{align*}
\lvert I_p(A,B;C)-I_q(A,B;C)\rvert\leq\log\lvert\mathcal{B}\rvert.
\end{align*}
where $\mathcal{B}$ is the alphabet set of $B$ and $I(.;.)$ is the mutual information.

Comment: By $AB$, do you mean the vector $(A,B)$ or do you mean the product?  And there seems to be a typo in your definition of $q$.

Comment: I mean $(A,B)$. No, only instead of $p_B$ we have $q_{B|A}$.

Comment: What are $p_A$ and $q_{B|A}$?

Comment: $p_A$ is pmf of random variable $A$ and $q_{B|A}$ is conditional pmf of $B$ conditioned on $A$.

Comment: How does that differ from $p_{B|A}?$

Comment: Oh, wait.  Perhaps you mean that you have different distributions on the set $\mathcal{A} \times \mathcal{B} \times \mathcal{C}$?

Comment: Yes. $q$ and $p$ are two different distributions on $\mathcal{A}\times\mathcal{B}\times\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52596/discussion-between-mohammad-mahdi-and-pat-devlin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set-up is the following.

> We have random variables $A,B,C$ and $A', B', C'$. We know $A$ and $A'$ have the same distribution, and for all $(a,b)$, the random variable $C | (A,B)=(a,b)$ has the same distribution as $C' | (A', B') = (a,b)$.

Under the above hypothesis, the claim you want is in fact false.  Here's a counterexample.

Let $A$ and $A'$ be uniformly distributed over $\{1, 2, \ldots, a\}$.  Let $B$ and $B'$ be independently drawn from $\{0,1\}$ such that $\mathbb{P}(B=0) = \mathbb{P}(B'=1) = \varepsilon$.  And let $C = AB$ and $C' = A' B'$ be the product of the other two.

(I'm allowing the $\varepsilon$ in there just so that we don't have to condition on any events having probability $0$ in the definitions of $C$ and $C'$, but you should imagine $\varepsilon \approx 0$.  And every $\approx$ below becomes equality in the limit as $\varepsilon \to 0$.)

Then we have $H(A,B) = H(A', B') = H(A) + H(B) \approx H(A) = \log(a)$.  On the other hand, $H(A,B | C) \approx 0$ since with probability $1-\varepsilon$, $(A,B)$ is uniquely determined by $C$.  Similarly $H(A', B' | C') \approx H(A')$ since $C'$ usually tells us nothing about $A'$.  This give us

$$
I(A, B; C) - I(A', B'; C') = H(A,B) - H(A,B|C) - [H(A',B') - H(A',B'|C')] = H(A',B'|C') - H(A,B|C) \approx \log(a),
$$
which can be made arbitrarily large.